# MLE estimation of Autoregressive Conditional Poisson model

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution, likelihood, autoregressive

The density of an Autoregressive Conditional Poisson ACP(p,q) model is defined as

$$ f(x | \lambda_{t}) = \frac{\lambda_{t}^{x}\exp[-\lambda_{t}]}{x!},$$

where

$$\lambda_{t} = \omega + \sum_{j = 1}^{p}\alpha_{j}(x_{t-j}) + \sum_{j = 1}^{q}\beta_{j}(\lambda_{t-j}).$$

I'm trying to estimate the three parameters of an ACP(1,1) model, thus:

$$ f(x | \lambda_{t}) = \frac{\lambda_{t}^{x}\exp[-\lambda_{t}]}{x!},$$

where

$$\lambda_{t} = \omega + \alpha (x_{t-1}) + \beta(\lambda_{t-1}),$$

with $\omega$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ non-negative.

The likelihood of this ACP(1,1) should be:

$$ L(\lambda_{t} | x) = \prod_{i = 1}^{n} f(x_{i}|\lambda_{t}),$$

and thus the loglikelihood should be

$$ l(\lambda_{t} | x) = \log \left(\prod_{i = 1}^{n} f(x_{i}|\lambda_{t})\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\log(f(x_{i}|\lambda_{t})) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\log \left( \frac{\lambda_{t}^{x_{i}} \exp{[-\lambda_{t}]}}{x_{i}!}\right) = $$

$$ = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right) \log(\lambda_{t}) - n\lambda_{t} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(x_{i}!) = $$

$$ = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}\right) \log(\omega + \alpha (x_{t-1}) + \beta(\lambda_{t-1})) - n(\omega + \alpha (x_{t-1}) + \beta(\lambda_{t-1})) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log(x_{i}!) $$

I'm trying to minimize such a loglikelihood by means of the BFGS algorithm using the following Python code, but it does not work.

```
polio = [0,1,0,0,1,3,9,2,3,5,3,5,2,2,0,1,0,1,3,3,2,1,1,5,0,3,1,0,1,4,0,0,1,6,14,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,2,0,3,1,1,0,2,0,4,0,2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,2,1,3,1,2,4,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2,2,4,2,3,3,0,0,2,7,8,2,4,1,1,2,4,0,1,1,1,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,1,3,6]

def loglikelihood(params, data):
    (omega, alpha_1, beta_1) = params
    t = np.array(data)
    loglik = 0
    mu = 0
    for i in xrange(1,len(t)):
        mu = omega + alpha_1 * t[i-1] + beta_1 * mu
        loglik += t[i] * math.log(mu) - mu - math.log(math.factorial(t[i]))    
    print -loglik
    return -loglik

estimates = scipy.optimize.minimize(loglikelihood, (0.01, 0.01, 0.01), method = 'BFGS', args = (polio,))
(omega, alpha, beta) =  estimates.x
```

Can you check if the likelihood is well specified?

EDIT:

I figured out that one problem was in the optimization procedure. Since $\omega$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$ need to be positive, I had to use a different optimization algorithm and specify three constraints.

```
bnds = ((1e-3, None), (1e-3, None), (1e-3, None))

def loglikelihood(params):
    (omega, alpha, beta) = params
    t = np.array(polio)
    loglik = 0
    mu = 0
    for i in xrange(1,len(t)):
        mu = omega + alpha * t[i-1] + beta * mu
        loglik += t[i] * math.log(mu) - mu - math.log(math.factorial(t[i]))
    return -loglik

estimates = scipy.optimize.minimize(loglikelihood, (0.1, 0.1, 0.1), method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds, options = {'maxiter': 1e4})
(omega, alpha, beta) =  estimates.x
```

Still, the minimization procedure does not converge. Maybe a problem in the specification of the loglikelihood?

Comment: `math.log(math.factorial` will cause problems (and is superfluous, anyway).  Don't use artificial bounds: instead consider reparameterizing the model, for example by using their logarithms.

Answer (score 0):

I use your code with slight housekeeping and it works for me! Please see here-

```
polio =[0,1,0,0,1,3,9,2,3,5,3,5,2,2,0,1,0,1,3,3,2,1,1,5,0,3,1,0,1,4,0,0,1,6,14,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,2,0,0,1,2,0,3,1,1,0,2,0,4,0,2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,2,1,3,1,2,4,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2,2,4,2,3,3,0,0,2,7,8,2,4,1,1,2,4,0,1,1,1,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,2,0,0,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,1,3,6]

bnds = ((1e-3, None), (1e-3, None), (1e-3, None))

def loglikelihood(params):
    (omega, alpha, beta) = params
    t = np.array(polio)
    loglik = 0
    mu = 0
    for i in range(1,len(t)):
        mu = omega + alpha * t[i-1] + beta * mu
        loglik += t[i] * np.log(mu) - mu - np.log(np.math.factorial(t[i]))
    return -loglik

estimates = scipy.optimize.minimize(loglikelihood, (0.1, 0.1, 0.1), method = 'SLSQP', bounds = bnds, options = {'maxiter': 1e4})
(omega, alpha, beta) =  estimates.x
estimates.x
```

I get omega = 0.64001, alpha = 0.35013 and beta = 0.18367.

Comment: Can you please also explain in words what you did?